# Connecting AspNetUsers to customers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I want administrators to be able to assign AspNetUser to a specific customer.  The relationship is supposed to be that multiple logins (AspNetUsers) have a foreign key to the same customer. To do so i added the following property to my identityModel.

```
public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
```

The column is added to the db; so far so good.

When I try to update the ApplicationUser entity with an instance of an ApplicationUserManager no exception is thrown and the view is returned. Nonetheless no changes to the db. When debugging i see that the customer gets set for the user, so I'm wondering if there is anything I'm missing?

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Email,Customer")] ApplicationUser user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ApplicationUserManager applicationUserManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));
            var customerName = Request.Form["customerSelect"];
            var customer = db.Customers.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Name == customerName);
            user.Customer = customer;
            await applicationUserManager.UpdateAsync(user);
            return RedirectToAction("index");

        }
        return View(user);
    }
```

I thought of creating a new entity that maps AspNetUser.Id to Customer.Id, but i would prefer not to.